# Set a default open state for an Angular JS collapsing Bootstrap DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap collapsing div that I've adapted for Angular JS:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#radios" class="data-toggle" collapse>Radio Buttons</legend>
    <div id="radios" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <!-- add class "collapse" to start out closed -->
    <div class="panel-body">
        ...stuff...
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Where You set the class `collapse` on the panel to have it start out closed (as here) or omit it to have it start open.

I've written this directive to toggle the class of the item being clicked, to display an "open" or "closed" icon:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('designSystemApp')
  .directive('collapse', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.on({
                click: function(e) {
                    element.toggleClass('open');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It works great like this, when it start of closed and toggles open and closed.

Since the BS way is to set the class on the child object (panel) I'm not sure how to have that affect the Angular trigger object, so changing that class will set the state/class to "open" at the start.

In other words, if I remove the class the div starts open **but** the `legend` does not have the open class so the icon is "closed".  I'm trying to avoid having to set two things; lookin for an easy way to set the default as open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly answering, but providing you with a possible workaround/solution to your question I am doing a similar task using the `angular-bootstrap` library for this and other bootstrap controls. The library can be found [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

An example of the collapse plugin adapted for your use case:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Radio Buttons</legend>
  <div id="radios" class="panel-collapse" collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="panel-body">
        ...stuff...
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Then in your angular directive or controller you could set `isCollapsed = true or false` depending whether you want it to start open or closed by default.